# Reading from a ZipArchiveEntry cause exception and MemoryLeak if using a MemoryStream

Tags: c#

I have the following code that generate two kinds of errors. First with the current code I get an exception 'NotSupportedException: This stream from ZipArchiveEntry does not support reading.'. How am I supposed to read the data ?

Furthermore if i use a MemoryStream (as the commented code )  then I can read the data and deserialize correctly but the memorystream i created still remains in memory even if the dispose method  has been called on it  , causing some memory leaks . Any idea what is wrong with this code ?

```
void Main()
{
    List<Product> products;
    using (var s = GetDb().Result)
    {
        products = Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(s).ToList();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static Task<Stream> GetDb()
{
    var filepath = Path.Combine("c:/users/tom/Downloads", "productdb.zip");
    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filepath))
    {
        var data = archive.Entries.Single(e => e.FullName == "productdb.json");
        return Task.FromResult(data.Open());
        //using (var reader = new StreamReader(data.Open()))
        //{
        //    var ms = new MemoryStream();
        //    data.Open().CopyTo(ms);
        //    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //    return Task.FromResult((Stream)ms);
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the commented code you open the stream into a reader, don't use the reader, then open the stream again and copy over to the memory stream without closing the second opened stream.

It is the second opened stream that remains in memory, not the `MemoryStream`.

Refactor

```
public static async Task<Stream> GetDb() {
    var filepath = Path.Combine("c:/users/tom/Downloads", "productdb.zip");
    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filepath)) {
        var entry = archive.Entries.Single(e => e.FullName == "productdb.json");
        using (var stream = entry.Open()) {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake. Unfortunately it does not solve my issue if I set a breakpoint after the block `using (var s = GetDb().Result)` i still have a memorystream in memory.  I have done a simple test of creating MMemoryStream that inherit from MemoryStream and I have been able to spot that it is actually the memorystream that i am returning from GetDb that stays and leak.